# Android login page against brute force attack

Tags: android, authentication, timer, brute-force

I am making an application where I have a web login activity. I want to keep it secured from brute forces. What I am trying is that the activity will lock after 3 unsuccessful attempts and will get unlocked after 15 minutes. I have successfully implemented the former part, i.e. locking the activity(by disabling its **Button** and **EditText**) after 3 unsuccessful tries. Now I want to do the later part where the activity will be unlocked(the EditText and Button).
How do I do it?

Comment: use alarmmanager and service to lock and unlock

Comment: Just record the `Date` when the login will be available again and at each login attempt check if that `Date` has passed. But on a side note: Do you really think that this makes your app more secure? If anything than it makes your app more annoying for the user. Plus is there any reason you are not implementing this functionality in your backend? Anybody who really wants to get around this will get around it. And you can't do anything to prevent people from getting around it.

Comment: recording a date has a flaw. If the last attempt is on 23.59 hours then the user will be able to try again after 00:00 hours. And yes I have taken that point and will implement it later. But first I need to do this.

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira can you help me with any tutorial or code?

Comment: @user3608017 I have absolutely **NO** idea what "flaw" you are talking about. What you stated is just not true.

Comment: Using `AlarmManager` is total overkill. And introduces a lot more unnecessary complexity and errors you need to handle. Don't use that...

Comment: Just save yourself the time and implement it in the backend. Implementing this in your app has no purpose whatsoever aside from annoying your users.